# Определение workspace для multibranch проекта в Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Добрый день. В Jenkins есть multi-branch project. По умолчанию в таком случае Jenkins определяет workspace следующим образом:

*/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MainJobName*

Для каждой новой ветки этой же Job'ы он так же определяет workspace, там же:

*/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MainJobName-Branch1*
*/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MainJobName-Branch2*

Вместо branch_1 он подставляет SHA, но это не важно. Так вот, есть необходимость вынести проект в отдельный workspace, и такая опция есть в Advanced Project Options -> Use Custom Workspace. Однако в этом случае он использует один workspace на все ветки. И в таком случае собирается только одна ветка. В help'e на эту тему есть вот что:

> Also, you can map multiple projects to have the same workspace, but if
>   you do so, make sure concurrent executions of those jobs won't have
>   nasty interference with each other.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Пусть бы он обрабатывал каждую ветку так же как и при работе в default workspace, просто в другом месте. На отдельном харде, например.

Comment: Есть баг, что дженкинс не удаляет воркспейсы, когда удаляет job'ы в multi-branch project. Следите за ним )

Comment: Спасибо за предупреждение.